# Laravel: Filter many to many on multiple values

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a layered navigation module for my laravel application - Much like is done in Magento or WooCommerce. This is the idea: **Products can be assigned single or multiple attributes and users then should be able to filter the products down by using these attributes**. Like the attribute "material" where products can be assigned one or more values like *iron*, *wood* & *plastic*. My problem is that I can't figure out how to do this properly.

My datamodel is like this:

```
         products table:  id | name         | other info...
                example:  42 | Chair        | ...
                example:  14 | Bike         | ...

       attributes table:  id | name         | description
                example:  02 | Material     | the material that the...

attribute_options table:  id | attribute_id | value    
                example:  11 | 02           | Wood    
                example:  12 | 02           | Iron    

            pivot table:  id | product_id   | attribute_option_id    
                example:  12 | 42           | 11    
                example:  12 | 42           | 12    
                example:  12 | 14           | 12
```

I've set a many to many relation between the **Product** and **Product Option** models (hence the pivot table).

In my view file a form is displayed which loops over all the different attributes and then loops over their options and creates a **checkbox for each of the options with a value of their id's**. The values are ideally grouped together in one array and named like this: **filter[attribute_id][attribute_option_id]**. An example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[02][11]" value="id"> Wood
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[02][12]" value="id"> Iron
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[xx][xx]" value="id"> Etc..
```

On submitting the form all the selected attribute option values are send to the server to a route where this information should be processed and only products that meet all different criteria should be returned.

So if filters[02][11] and [02][12] would be posted, only products should be returned that have the attribute options of "Wood" and "Iron" assigned.

At first, I thought this would be quite simple, but I think I'm not as skilled as I thought I would be... Since this is a Laravel question, I'd love for a eloquent style solution!

*P.S. If I messed up the (thinking behind my) datamodel, please tell me! I'm still learning a lot of stuff about web development and maybe there is a much better/cleaner solution/approach to my problem*

**-------- EDIT / ADDITIONAL INFORMATION --------**

With the following code I can filter for one attribute

```
$products = $products->whereHas('attributeOptions', function($query)
{
    $query->where(function($query)
    {
        $query->where('value', 'iron');
    });
});
```

But since products can have multiple attributes of different types (like color and material or multiple materials) I need to be able to set multiple wheres like this:

```
$products = $products->whereHas('attributeOptions', function($query)
{
    $query->where(function($query)
    {
        $query->where('value', 'iron');
        $query->where('value', 'wood');
        $query->where('value', 'yellow');
    });
});
```

But this code doesn't work since it checks for one row having multiple values instead of checking for values on multiple rows with the same product_id.

The relation between **products** and **attribute_options** is:

```
public function attributeOptions() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('AttributeOption', 'products_attribute_options', 'product_id', 'attribute_option_id');

}
```

Is this even possible in Eloquent/Laravel or do I need a different solution

**Thanks in advance, I'd love to learn from you!**

Comment: I guess you are looking for the faceted search pattern ? Looping through the products and building the filters in the view is not a good idea. you must keep a separate table for all your filter attributes.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was searching for! Now I need to find good study material on this matter. I'd love to build a faceted search feature like WooCommerce has. There you can filter products down with checkboxes and range sliders, which is really conveniant.

Comment: This is more a database issue than a Laravel one.  You need to first decide how you want to query your EAV data.  For example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762829/how-to-implement-filter-system-in-sql.  And:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764290/what-is-best-performance-for-retrieving-mysql-eav-results-as-relational-table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with @astro and @Dave from the comments. You should rethink your database design. I'll repost the two links from @Dave here so they gain more visibility for others:

[How to implement filter system in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2762829/1903366)

[What is best performance for Retrieving MySQL EAV results as Relational Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8764290/1903366)

---

While I don't think this works well in terms of performance (with many attributes and products) here is a solution that should work with your current setup:

Change your checkboxes to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[02][]" value="11"> Wood
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[02][]" value="12"> Iron
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[xx][]" value="xx"> Etc..
```

This way multiple values for the same filter will be added as a numeric array to `filter[02][]`

```
$query = Product::query();
foreach(Input::get('filter') as $attributeId => $optionIds){
    foreach($optionIds as $optionId){
        $query->whereHas('attributeOptions', function($q) use ($attributeId, $optionId){
            $q->where('attributeId', $attributeId)
              ->where('attribute_option_id', $optionId);
        }
    }
}
$products = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would approach this by using the whereHas method, and then using a whereIn to isolate records which contain the desired attributes, then filtering down that to only those records which have the correct number of attributes.

```
// Assuming you have the IDs of the attributes, rather than the value
$desiredAttributes = [11,12];
$products = $products->whereHas('attributeOptions', function($query)     
use($desiredAttributes)
{
    $query->whereIn('attribute_id', $desiredAttributes);
}, "=", count($desiredAttributes))->get();
```

So this would first go get all the records which have attributes 11 or 12, and then filter down to only records which have count(attribute_option_id) == 2

Comment: I'm sorry but this returns an error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'attribute_options' (SQL: select * from `products` where (select count(*) from `attribute_options` inner join `attribute_options` on `attribute_options`.`id` = `attribute_options`.`attribute_option_id` where `attribute_options`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and `attribute_id` in (11, 12)) = 2)

Comment: I believe you will need to swap the whereIn to have attribute_option_id rather than attribute_id; Failing that I can try recreating your model and tables later.