# Laravel whereIn subquery

Tags: laravel, subquery, eloquent, where-clause

Let's say I have these tables: `users`, `languages`, `language_user`. The last one is a pivot table with an additional field `rating` that defines the level of competence of a User for that particular language (mother tongue, good, not good, ...).
I know how to get all users that can speak at least one of a particular set of languages:

```
$query->whereHas('languages', function($qry){                           
    $qry->whereIn("languages.id", [1, 8, 999]);                             
});
```

But what if I also want to filter based on `rating` for each language? So I want a User that can speak language 1 with a `rating` of 5, or language 8 with a `rating` of at least 3?

I tried with a loop inside the `whereIn` closure to iterate over all values and added a `where` subquery to match a particular value, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your inner query:

```php
$query->whereHas('languages', function($query)
{    
    foreach ([1 => 5, 8 => 3] as $language => $rating)
    {
        $query->where(function($query) use ($language, $rating)
        {
            $query->where('languages.id', $language)
                  ->where('languages.rating', '>=' $rating);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Almost there! The solution (almost identical to yours) has been posted in SO: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160607/laravel-filter-many-to-many-on-multiple-values#answer-28376060)